# Splitting string on commas when data can contain commas

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a CSV file (which I didn't design and I can't change now nor will I ever be able to change it) that contains lines like the following:

`"Surname, Firstname", yes, no, somestring, whatever, etc`

As you can see here, the first `,` is not a comma on which I'd want to split the string. Notice that this particular comma is enclosed within the quotation marks.

Because of this, a simple `string.split(',')` obviously won't work, as it would give me an array of length 7 for the above string instead of 6.

Is there a way to get around this? I was thinking of using regex to split the string instead but I'm not competent enough in regex to think of a pattern that would only split on commas that are not enclosed inside quotation marks.

I can think of ugly, hacky ways to do it by reading each string char by char but this would have to be a last resort as I'm sure there's a better way to do it!

Comment: This looks like a .csv from Excel.  Always fun.  More fun is when the data contains quotes and commas...

Comment: It's not actually from Excel, but yea, fun! :) It's from a location on the net, my program reads the file and attempts to parse it.

Comment: Reading one character at a time is not necessarily an ugly hack. I'd recommend finding a C# CSV parser, since I'm sure such things exist already.

Comment: As an ugly hack solution, you could always read the first char of an element, if it's a quote, advance your counter and add the next index value to the previous and continue.

Comment: +1 @Brian Donovan. It doesn't matter how elegant your code is if it doesn't work. Also, what happens if values contain `"` characters - are they doubled? escaped?

Comment: @AakashM, not totally sure what happens when the value contains a `"`, from what I can see in this file that particular situation doesn't arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there's a lot of people here who think character-by-character comparisons should never be used and will strongly disagree with me but I'm not convinced companies like Microsoft aren't the only ones who should be doing that sort of programming.

Afterall, Split does character-by-character comparisons so why is it any less ugly when you call existing code that doesn't quite do exactly what you want?

At any rate, my approach was to write my own code. And I've posted the code online at http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/files/reading-and-writing-csv-files-in-c.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I'm a little confused as to how to use your code, I'm not sure why I need to pass a parameter to ReadRow()?

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks Jonathan.

Comment: Good to hear it. Most of the articles include a demo project but not that one. Thanks for letting me know it might not be obvious to everyone how that method should be called. I'll look at updating that.

Answer (score 5):

You can handle this easily by using the [TextFieldParser class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx).  Just set [`HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.hasfieldsenclosedinquotes.aspx) to true.

Comment: You are referencing a .NET 4.5 visual basic Class when this was posted as a C# question.

Comment: @aggaton Just because the type is in the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace, doesn't mean it can't be used from C#.  `TextFileParser` works great from C#, and it's part of the core framework - there's no reason to avoid it.

Comment: @ReedCopsey it's `TextFieldParser`, though, not `TextFileParser`. You managed to link to the right thing but consistently write it wrong.

Comment: Note that `HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes` should probably only be set if _all_ fields are enclosed in quotes. I left he option off, and it worked perfectly when parsing an MS Excel export where only the fields containing quotes or commas were surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a CSV parser library - there are other cases that you wouldn't have thought of (new line as part of a quoted field).

The `VisualBasic` namespace has a nice library that can help - the [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx).

Comment: C# devs shouldn't worry about the VisualBasic namespace.  Means nothing IRL, adds no dependencies that aren't on the machine, etc.

Comment: Beautiful, and as @Will said, works just fine when used in C#. Why does Microsoft hide away tools like this in such odd places?